# FFT on spice data (time, value) frequency axis not correct

Tags: python, scipy, fft

I have two numpy arrays (one for the time, one for the value) imported from a spice export text-file. The file contains a sinus of 1kHz.

When plotting the FFT with the use of the plotSpectrum function [(link here)](http://glowingpython.blogspot.be/2011/08/how-to-plot-frequency-spectrum-with.html) the output does not match the 1kHz, it is around 891Hz.

Any suggestions what could have gone wrong? I've calculated the dt between the first 4 time samples and they are equally spaced. Does spice not equally spaces all samples in an export file? Or what could have gone wrong? Doe I need to limit the array to a power of 2?

Thanks for any help!

My full code looks like

```
import numpy
from pylab import plot, show, title, xlabel, ylabel, subplot
from scipy import fft, arange
import pylab

data = numpy.loadtxt('sin1k.txt', delimiter='\t')

time = data[:,0]
value = data[:,1]



def plotSpectrum(y,Fs):
 """
 Plots a Single-Sided Amplitude Spectrum of y(t)
 """
 n = len(y) # length of the signal
 k = arange(n)
 T = n/Fs
 frq = k/T # two sides frequency range
 frq = frq[range(n/2)] # one side frequency range

 Y = fft(y)/n # fft computing and normalization
 Y = Y[range(n/2)]

 plot(frq,abs(Y),'r') # plotting the spectrum
 xlabel('Freq (Hz)')
 ylabel('|Y(freq)|')


subplot(2,1,1)
plot(time,value)
xlabel('Time')
ylabel('Amplitude')
subplot(2,1,2)
plotSpectrum(value,(time[1]-time[0])*10e9)
pylab.xlim([0,2000])
show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that spice got me by not equally spacing all 2907 samples; some where equally spaced, others not! My 4 samples happened to be equally spaced.

I've spaced the samples equally with Paul Wagner's library (link [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23394-fast-import-of-compressed-binary-raw-files-created-with-ltspice-circuit-simulator/content/LTspice2Matlab.m)), thank you Paul!

And the fft turned out to be 1045Hz which is more reasonable.

Comment: In ngspice, use the LINEARIZE command. No need for extra tools.